# PDF Merge using iTextSharp in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

I have the code for my pdf merge application but I need help on how to make this all work. I need help on the winforms Design. Obviously its just a blank screen right now without the design.

Below you will see my form code which is labeled form1.cs and program.cs which is below

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}

form1.cs

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Folder that we'll work from
            string workingFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            string pdf1 = Path.Combine(workingFolder, "pdf1.pdf");//PDF with solid red background color
            string pdf2 = Path.Combine(workingFolder, "pdf2.pdf");//PDF with text
            string pdf3 = Path.Combine(workingFolder, "pdf3.pdf");//Merged PDF

            //Create a basic PDF filled with red, nothing special
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdf1, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER))
                {
                    using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
                    {
                        doc.Open();
                        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                        cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
                        cb.Rectangle(0, 0, doc.PageSize.Width, doc.PageSize.Height);
                        cb.Fill();
                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            //Create a basic PDF with a single line of text, nothing special
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdf2, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER))
                {
                    using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
                    {
                        doc.Open();
                        doc.Add(new Paragraph("This is a test"));
                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            //Create a basic PDF
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdf3, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER))
                {
                    using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
                    {
                        doc.Open();

                        //Get page 1 of the first file
                        PdfImportedPage imp1 = writer.GetImportedPage(new PdfReader(pdf1), 1);
                        //Get page 2 of the second file
                        PdfImportedPage imp2 = writer.GetImportedPage(new PdfReader(pdf2), 1);
                        //Add the first file to coordinates 0,0
                        writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(imp1, 0, 0);
                        //Since we don't call NewPage the next call will operate on the same page
                        writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(imp2, 0, 0);
                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            this.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be a working Pdf Merge/combine to where it has two buttons asking which file to upload for the parent pdf and then another button for child pdf and then something that shows the child pdf merged into the parent pdf.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Does anyone know how to use proper code to use on the design to have a button that says add files and then browses the files in the system and then shows both files that the user added and then a seperate button for merge pdf files